# XCode Project with Podfile - Git Repo

Tags: xcode, podfile

Which files of a XCode Project should I upload to my git repo to build the project from any computer? The project was generated by Apache Cordova. I supose that it is enough uploading the `.xcodeproj` and the `podfile`. But if I open the `.xcodeproj` how can I tell XCode that as pre-build action should download the packages specified in the podfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Cocoapods`, after `pod install`, you can see a `Podfile.lock`, `Pods` folder and  `.xcworkspace`.

- `Podfile.lock`: the lockfile for the dependencies. Usually, you got the version info of the dependencies.
- `Pods` : usually, can ignore this in `.gitignore` file. It contains the dependencies for your projects, those you specified in the Podfile and their own dependencies.
- `.xcworkspace`. Right click it -> Show Packages Contents.

  [image]

  - you can ignore `xcuserdata`, it contains local info about the user. It will be changed when other users open this `.xcworkspace`
  - ignore the `xcshareddata`, it has info about the IDE.
  - while the `contents.cxworkspacedata` contains a reference to your project and `Pods.xcodeprojc`, which is generated by `pod install` to manager your dependency targets.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workspace
   version = "1.0">
   <FileRef
      location = "group:YourOwnProject.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
   <FileRef
      location = "group:Pods/Pods.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
</Workspace>
```

When your colleagues pull your changes, run `Pod install` locally to generate the missing `Pods/*` and `Open xxx. xcworkspace`.

- https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore
- https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore